# Running a python script on an Android device

Tags: python, android, adb, termux

I need to control an android app using a python script.
Currently, I connect my phone to my laptop and use adb (android debug bridge).

Process:

1. Laptop sends an adb shell command to android to take a snapshot of the screen
2. Android sends the snapshot to my laptop for processing
3. Python/laptop will process the snapshot by analyzing a series of pixels to detect a change in shapes on screen and decide what action to take (tap, swipe, ...)
4. Python/laptop will send an adb shell tap or swipe command to the android device
5. Android will execute the action

The only problem is that this process

Is there a way to have the python script live on the android device directly making decisions and taking actions?
The closest I have found so far is using Termux, but what library could I use to replace adb? (To see the content of the screen, send tap/swipe actions?)

Comment: You should explain what `Python/laptop will process the snapshot and decide what action to take (tap, swipe, ...)` means as moving image processing analysis onto the mobile device will probably not make things faster. Also are you aware of using something like [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy) to drive the mobile device

Comment: edited -- also, I did hear of scrcpy, but it is similar to using adb. It still has noticeable delays and it needs my laptop's help. I suspect that running the python script directly on the device might be faster. But I am not sure how to interact with the device's inputs using python. @MorrisonChang

Comment: See: [How to run adb and fastboot commands from Termux?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/183554/3573), but note that root may be required. Also note that you can [change animation speed in developer options](https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/dev-options#drawing)

Comment: Oh, didn't know there was an andoid StackOverflow community -- I will repost question there https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/242822/running-a-python-script-on-an-android-device thanks @MorrisonChang

Comment: I did this couple of years ago with ruby - I used GNURoot https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=champion.gnuroot Problem was reach adb, I think hotspot creation fixed it